# How to verify an foreign key in Strongloop?

Tags: javascript, json, loopbackjs, upsert

I have a list of categories and a list of places, each place has an categorieId in foreign key.

categorie.json: http://pastebin.com/ttumKPf9

place.json: http://pastebin.com/J4bdEiUx

I try to verify if the category id exists. For this, i redefine a create method in place class. In place class I search if the category id is present in category. If i find it, i call upsert method for insert the data in place.
But this upsert method recall create method...
If i don't call upsert method, the data isn't insert.
How can I verify and insert the data in strongloop?

*script.js:*

```
module.exports = function(app){

 var Place = app.models.place;
 var Categorie = app.models.categorie;

 Place.create = function(data,callback){
  console.log("avant find");

    console.log(data.id);

    Categorie.findById(data.categorieId, function(err, instance){
      console.log("find")

      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
      if(instance == null){
        new err;
        throw err;
      }

      console.log("Upsert");
      Place.upsert(data, callback);
    });  
 };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redefine remote method, not the ORM method.

Another approach, if you use relational DB, create foreign key constraints.

Here is the SQL query, where `place` and `categorie` are table names: 
`ALTER TABLE place ADD CONSTRAINT Categorie_places_ix FOREIGN KEY (categorieId) REFERENCES categorie(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;`

Comment: I try it, but the foreign key isn't verify by Strongloop. How can I use the belongsTo relation?

Comment: Create hasMany relation, and this will expose endpoints, like `POST:/api/category/:id/place`. This is what you need?

Also you can execute raw SQL commands directly or in boot section, on your own (I can provide some examples)

Comment: belongsTo allowing you to retrieve `category`, that owns `place`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i would be willing examples if you propose it.

Comment: I completed the answer, just execute SQL query in the shell. The same, but with inserting query to boot section is tricky :)